# How to access all request headers that browser sent in PHP 5.3 or lesser?

Tags: php, php-5.3

I want to access to all the request headers that the client (browser) sent to my web server. PHP 5.3.3 is installed on my web server.

Observations so far:

- [`http_get_request_headers()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-get-request-headers.php) doesn't seem to work, maybe php 5.3.3 doesn't support it.
- [`getallheaders()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php) is also not supported by 5.3.
- [`apache_request_headers()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) is also not defined in 5.3.

Is there any other built-in function or any other method which can be used to access **all** request headers that my client (browser) sent.

Comment: Let me guess? You're running PHP via FastCGI? Docs say _"[PHP version] 5.4.0  This function became available under FastCGI. Previously, it was supported only when PHP was installed as an Apache module._"

Comment: Use `$_SERVER` directly then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get by doing this:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

more array indices available [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me what all fields correspond to what all key values in $_SERVER array?

Comment: @AyushMishra i didn't understood your question !! can you ask in a different way  :D

Comment: But, I understood your answer. Thanks! ^_^